# How to update firebase database values automatically as admin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have following scenario for my games sign up process:

User signs up with email and password and is asked to verify the account. After verification their account is created. User is redirected to `character creation` process, they will also be redirected there if they log in and have not yet created character. After user creates character they are directed into the game, now as they have character they will also be logged in straight into game.

So I now need an entry inside my `user: {}` in firebase database that tracks this character creation state i.e. `user: { status: 'CREATING_CHARACTER' }` and `user: { status: 'CHARACTER_CREATED' }` that will let me know what screen they need to be shown after login. This state should only be able to update by admin I believe i.e. user can auth and should not be able to set this unless they actually go through character creation process and complete this.

I am struggling to figure out how this flow would be handled in terms of security in firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    "status": {
      ".read": "data.root().child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists() || 
                $uid === auth.uid",
      ".write": "data.root().child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists() ||
                ($uid === auth.uid && data.exists() && data.val() !== newData.val())"
      ".validata": "newData.val() === 'CREATING_CHARACTER' || 
                    newData.val() === 'CHARACTER_CREATED'"
    }
  }
}
```

- users can read their own status, or if they are in "admins" group
- users from "admins" group can write status
- users can change their status if it already exists and it's different then existing one
- status can be set to `CREATING_CHARACTER` or `CHARACTER_CREATED`

You'll have to check if user finished creating character on the client. And if you want Admin only from firebase console, remove parts with 'admin' users from these rules.